# Use default user settings for each SVN repository?

Tags: svn

I frequently need to create new SVN-repositories with :

```
svnadmin create repo123
```

Then to get access to the repo, in the `conf` folder I need to change the `passwd` file :

```
[users]
User1=password1
```

and in `svnserve.conf` file uncomment the following lines:

```
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

For every new repository I have to do this.

My team has only 2 users, who have the same rights, so isn't there a way to use these settings automatically for every repository?

Or am I doing it completely wrong and do I need to use just 1 repository with sub-folders for each project?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to write your own script to do this.

Are you using the svn protocol and storing the passwords in clear text in that file?

There are GUI based tools that don't come with a huge overhead that might allow you to manage this more practically.

Check out 
svnmanager.sourceforge.net
visual SVN

As for how your repos are managed (one vs. many) - We'd need to know a bit more about how your code is structured/segregated. i.e. is it for different clients, apps etc?

Comment: yes, entirely different projects, but developed by the same team

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how many repositories you have so far... If you don't want a large transition overhead I would have thought a custom script to re-write your configuration files on repository creation would be the answer... Instead of calling svnadmin directly, have a script do it and makefile configuration changes at the same time

Comment: So there is no option in svnserve to define an admin user, like 'root' in mysql ?